# Create DataFrame where all data is in lists, but one has a nested list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have the following data:

**Dog:** Male, Brown, 10 Years, Sausage, Happy

**Cat:** Female, Black, 5 Years, Pippin, Angry

**Hamster:** Male, Yellow, 1 Year, Jeff, Moody

I receive the data structured as follows:

```
Animals = ['dog', 'cat', 'hamster']
Genders = ['male', 'female', 'male']
Properties = [
         ['Brown', '10 Years', 'Sausage', 'Happy'],
         ['Black', '5 Years', 'Pippin', 'Angry'],
         ['Yellow', '1 Year', 'Jeff', 'Moody']
      ]
```

Whereby the 'Properties' of the animal are in a list of their own.

I want to create a dataframe as follows:

```
  Animal  Gender  Colour  Age       Name     Sentiment
0 Dog     Male    Brown   10 Years  Sausage  Happy
1 ...
2
3
```

But I am struggling to loop through the 'Properties' list of lists to populate the columns correctly:

I have tried the following:

```
d = []
for pet in Animals:
    d.append({
        'Animal' : pet,
        'Gender' : gender,
        for j in Properties:
              'Colour' : Properties[0][j]
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

But this doesn't appear to be working correctly and I'm a little stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Let us try two step with `concat`

```
out = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'Animals':Animals,'Gender':Genders}),
                 pd.DataFrame(Properties,columns = ['Colour','Age','Name','Sentiment'])],
                 axis=1)

Out[82]: 
   Animals  Gender  Colour       Age     Name Sentiment
0      dog    male   Brown  10 Years  Sausage     Happy
1      cat  female   Black   5 Years   Pippin     Angry
2  hamster    male  Yellow    1 Year     Jeff     Moody
```

Comment: Hi @BENY, for some reason this is giving me the dog's properties for every row of the DF?